# Redirection after certain node type creating

Tags: redirection

So far i have this code in mymodule.module:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    //drupal_set_message($form_id);
    switch ($form_id) {

        case 'anons_node_form':
          //dpm($form);
          $form['#submit'][] = 'sex_custom_submit';

          break;
    }
}

//Custom submit handler
function sex_custom_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
  $form_state['redirect'] = '/video';
}
```

In a short i want this thing - when a user creates a node type 'anons' after succesfull creation of that node -> user should be redirected to a /video page. Code above doesn't works for me.. What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Why not sure Rules framework?

Answer (score 2):

Try putting your destination as GET destination parameter, i:e $_GET['destination']. The GET destination parameter gets the highest preference

Answer (score 0):

Your redirect isn't happening because you have set `$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;` which prevents the redirect from happening.

For appropriate documentation see [drupal_redirect_form](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_redirect_form/7)

Comment: With false its not working too

Comment: Have you read the documentation at the link I provided? It lists a bunch of reasons why the redirect may not be happening.